# Rails 4 Superclass mismatch in production only with admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I wrote a little portfolio app in Rails 4. It has an admin namespace to allow me to only expose certain controllers to public.

Everything works great when in development, but when I deploy to a production env (or switch to production on my dev machine) I get the following error:

```
superclass mismatch for class WorksController (TypeError)
```

My controller structure looks like this:

```
controllers ->
  admin ->
    admin_controller.rb
    portfolio ->
      works_controller.rb
  portfolio->
    works_controller.rb
```

As you can see, I namespaced works inside of portfolio.

The controllers are declared as following:

```
/controllers/admin/admin_controller
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController

/controllers/admin/portfolio/works_controller
class Admin::Portfolio::WorksController < Admin::AdminController

/controllers/portfolio/works_controller.rb
class Portfolio::WorksController < ApplicationController
```

Now for my routes.rb, note I am using Friendly ID so I used a custom route to have a pretty client facing url.

```
get '/portfolio/:id' => 'portfolio/works#show', as: 'portfolio_work'

namespace :admin do
  namespace :portfolio do
    resources :works
  end
end
```

So I know I must have screwed this up somehow, but I don't know how. The error I get is related to redeclaring a class, but I don't know how I managed to do so.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this fix after @ReggieB tried to help me. Turns out having my Devise model 'Admin' and a namespace also called 'Admin' creates problems (as it should).

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you redefine /controllers/admin/portfolio/works_controller line this:

```
module Admin
  class Portfolio::WorksController < AdminController
```

Comment: TypeError: Admin is not a module. This would be because I have a Devise model 'Admin' correct?